# ActiveMQ register listener to StompConnection

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, stomp

I'm using a variation of the example at http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/activemq/trunk/assembly/src/release/example/src/StompExample.java to receive message from a queue. What I'm trying to do is to keep listening to a queue and perform some action upon reception of a new message. The problem is that I couldn't find a way to register a listener to any of the related objects. I've tried something like:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    StompConnection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = new StompConnection();
        connection.open("localhost", 61613);
        connection.connect("admin", "activemq");
        connection.subscribe("/queue/worker", Subscribe.AckModeValues.AUTO);
        while (true) {
            StompFrame message = connection.receive();
            System.out.println(message.getBody());
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

but this doesn't work as a time out occurs after a few seconds (`java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out`). Is there anything I can do to indefinitely listen to this queue?

Answer (score 1):

ActiveMQ's StompConnection class is a relatively primitive STOMP client.  Its not capable of async callbacks on Message or for indefinite waits.  You can pass a timeout to receive but depending on whether you are using STOMP v1.1 it could still timeout early if a heart-beat isn't received in time.  You can of course always catch the timeout exception and try again.

For STOMP via Java you're better off using [StompJMS](https://github.com/fusesource/stompjms) or the like which behaves like a real JMS client and allows for async Message receipt.

Answer (score 0):

@Tim Bish: I tried StompJMS, but couldn't find any example that I could use (maybe you can provide a link). I 'fixed' the problem by setting the timeout to 0 which seems to be blocking.

Comment: I believe there are some examples in the source tree, just pull from Git and take a look.  I think ActiveMQ Apollo also ships with some examples using StompJMS.

Answer (score 0):

even i was facing the same issue.. you can fix this by adding time out to your receive() method.

Declare a long type variable.

```
long waitTimeOut = 5000;   //this is 5 seconds
```

now modify your receive function like below.

```
StompFrame message = connection.receive(waitTimeOut);
```

This will definitely work.